# Buildfire: Is This Plugin Compatible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webstorm, buildfire

Good morning guys,

I am a new to the app development space and I've been doing ton's of research on you Build fires development side. I know that their plugins are mostly built form Jquery, javascript and HTML5. I am in the middle of developing my own app for personal use. I would like to add a booking feautre so that people who use this app will be able to book through the app. I have found Bookly pro  on codecanyon. I was wondering if this plugin would work one it's uploaded onto buildfire. Currently I am using Webstorm by jetbrains. Is this plugin supported ?

https://codecanyon.net/item/bookly-booking-plugin-responsive-appointment-booking-and-scheduling/7226091?_ga=2.27917052.1775880257.1548850425-1006020502.1548850425&ref=ladela

Comment: That plugin is for Wordpress, a PHP-based CMS for websites.

Comment: This plugin won't work with progressive web apps even though build fire plugins are built using Javascript and Jquery ? It comes with a Json file too. Sorry I'm still new and am not understanding why it wont work. @chris G

Comment: It's built specifically for [Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/). You cannot use it for anything else except a Wordpress website. I'm not sure what's not to understand. It's a Wordpress plugin, not a Buildfire plugin.

Comment: Small comment: JQuery can be used in BuildFire plugins but isnt mandatory. Most are written in Angular and React